# Search Products by Tags in Shopify via GraphQL in Rails

Tags: shopify, ruby-on-rails-6, shopify-api

I am using rails Shopify API and using Storefront API to get the products from Shopify. We have a lot of tags applied on every product. I want to get all the products that include the tags, either "*PDF_REPORT_VITA_*" OR "*PDF_REPORT_VITA*"(specifically) OR both, and the query that I am posting is:

```
{:query=>"PDF_REPORT_VITA_* OR PDF_REPORT_VITA", :first=>10}
```

But the problem is I am getting amongst all, the products that were even tagged with 'PDF_REPORT_VITAEQ10_1' E.G. .
Is there a fix for this in the query. Can we do this via OR to match the tags?

Answer (score 0):

Is the flaw in your query? Note that correctly structured query strings have attributes of what the query should convey, usually. You might have more luck with something like:

`{"query": "tag:PDF_REPORT_VITA"}`

Without providing the tag: aspect, Shopify proably has a hard time figuring out what your query means.

Comment: Hi David, So actually if I do this I get empty results,it behaves like there is no field called tag or no product exists with this particular tag in the list of its tags.

Comment: I am not going to fix all your problems, but I do know that I search by tags in both products and orders, and my queries work fine, using this syntax.